# The server can't read data correctly from the client || c language

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I'm learning socket programming in C language and we've to write both a TCP client/server where the client sends a file to the server line by line so it can perform one of two operations(min,avg) on it to send the output back the client.

The input file follows the following format:

```
AVG 1 2 3 4 5 6
MIN 1 2 3 4 5 -8
MIN 1 2 3 0 5 6
```

The problem is the server only reads one line and calculates it, also the output in the client is followed by zeros for some reason!!

the server's code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h> 
#define  MAXLINE    4096

double average(int num[],int iterations); //to find the average value
int minimun(int num[],int iterations); //to find the minimum value
double get_op(char b[],int op); //to distinguish between the operations
int startswith(const char *pre, const char *str); //to find if the operatioon is valid only min or avg

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2){ //recieves portnumber
        printf("Missing port number please try again.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0 , line = 0;
    char SENDBUFFER[2048] = "\0";
    char recvBuff[2048] = "\0";
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 
    memset(recvBuff, '0', sizeof(recvBuff)); 
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 
    listen(listenfd, 4); //listens to 4 clients max
    while(1)
    {
        socklen_t szaddr = sizeof(serv_addr);
        connfd=accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,&szaddr);
        int pid; 
        if( (pid = fork()) == 0 ) { // Child
            close(listenfd);//close listening sock
            printf("Connected...");     
            while(1){
                read(connfd,recvBuff,sizeof(recvBuff)-1);
                int op;
                line++;
                double ans;
                if(startswith("AVG ",recvBuff)){
                    op = 1;
                    ans = get_op(recvBuff,1);
                    sprintf(SENDBUFFER," %f",ans);
                    strcat(recvBuff," = ");
                    strcat(recvBuff,SENDBUFFER);
                    write(connfd, recvBuff, strlen(recvBuff));
                } 
                if(startswith("MIN ",recvBuff)){
                    op = 2;
                    ans = get_op(recvBuff,2);
                    sprintf(SENDBUFFER," %f",ans);
                    strcat(recvBuff," = ");
                    strcat(recvBuff,SENDBUFFER);
                    write(connfd, recvBuff, strlen(recvBuff));
                } 
                else{
                    memset(SENDBUFFER, '0', sizeof(SENDBUFFER));
                    strcat(SENDBUFFER,"Unsupported Operation on Line #");
                    char *str = "";
                    sprintf(str, "%d", line);
                    strcat(SENDBUFFER,str);
                    write(connfd, SENDBUFFER, strlen(SENDBUFFER));
                    }
                }
         close(connfd);
         sleep(1);// child terminates
        }else {// Parent
            close(connfd); // close connected socket
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int minimun(int num[],int iterations){ 
    int c;
    int min = num[0];
    for (c = 0;c<iterations; c++){
            if (num[c] <= min){
            min = num[c];
            }
        }
    return min;
}
int startswith(const char *pre, const char *str){
    char cp;
    char cs;
    if (!*pre)
        return 1;
    while ((cp = *pre++) && (cs = *str++)){
        if (cp != cs)
            return 0;
    }
    if (!cs)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
double average(int num[],int iterations){
    int sum = 0,c = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i<iterations;i++){
        sum=sum+num[i];
    }
    avg=(double)sum/iterations;
    return avg;
}
double get_op(char b[],int op){
    int arr[2048], idx=0, d, l=0;
    char *p; int counter = 0;
    for (p = b; *p != 0; p+=l) {
            l = 1;
            if (isdigit(*p)){
                sscanf(p, "%d%n", &d, &l);
                arr[idx++] = d;
            }   
    }   
    if(op==1)//avg
        return average(arr,idx);
    else     //min
        return (double)(minimun(arr,idx));
}
```

and this is the client code:

```
/* Client Code - Client.c */
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#define  MAXLINE    4096
#define filename "path to file"

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char SENDBUFFER [MAXLINE] = "\0";
    char recvBuff   [MAXLINE] = "\0";
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    //int len; 
    int sockfd ;
    if(argc<5){
    printf("usage:serv_IP_addr, serv_port,num_of_microsec,nam_of_fil to read the input from\n");
    exit(0);}
    memset(SENDBUFFER, '0', sizeof(SENDBUFFER));
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    }
    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2])); // port
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    /* Attempt a connection */
    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0){
        printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *file; //file to read from
            file = fopen("file path", "r"); //path to file
            if (file == NULL){
                printf("File not found!\n");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Found file %s\n", filename);
            printf("Sending the file now\n");
            //write function
            while(fgets(SENDBUFFER, MAXLINE,file)!=NULL){
                write(sockfd, SENDBUFFER, sizeof(SENDBUFFER)-1);
            }
            //read function
            memset(recvBuff,'0',sizeof(recvBuff));
            int n ;
            while((n=read(sockfd,recvBuff,sizeof(recvBuff)-1))> 0){
                if(fputs(recvBuff,stdout)==EOF){
                    printf("\n Error : nothing recieved\n");
                }
            } 
            printf("\nDone Sending the File!\n");
            printf("Now Closing Connection.\n");
            fclose(file);
            close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

P.S: I added fork() because I'm trying to make the server handle up to 4 clients maximum while others wait,still not finished.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I think that one of the reasons why your question has not received much attention is that there is a lot of code to wade through.  I know it is hard with client-server network applications to avoid that, but it doesn't encourage people to look at the material.  Have you tried working up a simple 'echo' client-server pair, where your client sends a message to the server and the server simply sends it back with to the client with a little extra information (e.g. wrapping the message in square brackets (`[[the-message]]`) so that you can debug the communication first?

Comment: If you get the 'echo' client-server working, you can then add the processing that the server is supposed to do.  Note that you can debug that processing wholly separately from the communications.  You can write a function that is passed a string (or byte array and length) which does the relevant processing and copies the output into an output byte array or string.  You can test this without any network at all.  When both are working independently, you can integrate the two easily enough.